# How to filter down rows to include only first x number of months per grouping

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

My question is, is there a way to get the first/earliest date per grouping in a table and then filter the table to only include rows within the first x number of months of that first date, per grouping. Probably easiest to ask with example. Say I have the following table, and want to keep data for **first 6** months of each Group:

[image]

The resulting table would look like:

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HBtc.png]

Is there a way to accomplish this with DAX or M?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Group", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Quantity", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each let DateThisRow = [AllData][Date] in Table.SelectRows([AllData],each [Date] <= Date.AddMonths(List.Min(DateThisRow),6))),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Group", "Date", "Quantity"}, {"Group", "Date", "Quantity"})
in
#"Expanded Custom"
```

Starting from your original table setup, named as Table1 in Excel:

[image]

...it gives me this as an end result:

[image]

The number 6 near the end of the #"Added Custom" line in the M code above is the number of months.